# Confused on. Voltage

Tags: voltage

I am a beginner to electronics.
I am a little confused with what is voltage.

- is is a limiting source
- can a 9 volt batter turn into a 5v after using it

Comment: Voltage is like pressure, current is like flow. If you do some research you can find numerous questions on this site that are similar to this one on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

What is Voltage? For the experienced person it is simple, but is it? Let's take a look.

Most of us know what a magnetic field is. It is invisible but it can attract most objects. If you put a magnet underneath a piece of paper and you sprinkle some iron filings, then the filings line up and give you an impression of the  invisible magnetic field. (flux lines)

There is another type of invisible field. It is called an "electric field" This type of field is much like magnetism. It is invisible, has lines of flux and it can attract of repel ojects. It is voltage.

The nice situation is most of us have experience with volts. Scuff across a rug and your body will be charged to several thousands of volts. You can see the spark and feel the shock during discharge. (flowing current).

A little more specific. Voltage is a way of using numbers to describe an electric field. Such a field is measured in Volt per meter. A stronger field has more Volts per meter than a weaker field.

Now to our battery. Between the two poles of the battery an electric field is created with the materials of the poles and the chemical mass between them.

So there we are: Inside the battery we have an electric field and we can measure the voltage of that field over the poles (distance) of the battery.

Now if the battery gets depleted the chemicals become exhausted and the field strenght reduces. So the voltage becomes less.

I could try to explain more but there is a nice link explaining electric field perfectly. Succes: http://amasci.com/miscon/voltage.html

[image]

A 9 volt battery consists of 6 cells of 1.5 V in series. During use of such a battery an electro chemical process delivers the energy to the user. This process can continue until the battery is depleted. As you can see from the graph all batteries have a socalled discharge curve where the voltage is going down during use. This is also the case with your 9 volt battery. For the 9 volt battery you can look at the Zn/MngO2 curve. with values for one cell.

Comment: So the voltage reduces

Comment: Ahem. At the risk of complicating a beginner's life, I've had experience with NiMH battery packs under high load in which the voltage rose during the first half of the cycle (testing from full charge to 1.2 volts per cell in about 45 minutes). The effect was caused by internal heating affecting the chemistry and increasing the voltage. These were 5 A-hr cells in a 28 volt configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you discharge a 9V battery long enough, there will be a point at, for any discharge current, it delivers 5V.

But it's not clear what you're asking.

If you're asking if this is a way to get 5V from a 9V battery for a device that can't tolerate more than 5V, ... **no** it isn't.

Imagine you discharge a 9V battery to 5V and then use it to power an expensive microcontroller. Switch the device off, and the battery voltage will recover to maybe about 8V over the next hour or so. Which will not be good next time you switch on...

There are voltage regulators and buck converters for that purpose. If you need 5V, use one of them.

Comment: Guys the but I understood nothing

Comment: Can u guys go from wat is voltage

Comment: @user117064: Voltage can be really confusing to a beginner. So I understand your problem. In my answer I will include a link where you can read about voltage. Only the first two paragraphs

Comment: Where is the link buddy

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me know